# Particle System not showing in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I am using two particle systems on an object. When I go to render preview or material preview in the viewport I can see the particles perfectly fine. However, in the final render the particles are not visible at all. These are my settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried multiple things such as messing around with frame start and end values, and rendering different frames, but nothing seems to work.

Also, something strange happens when I simply click to select a different particle system slot (out of the two I have), the particles in the viewport disappear for some reason, and I have to select a new frame via the timeline for them to come back to view. If more screenshots need to be provided, tell me what information I should provide since I don't know what could be causing this issue.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you baked the simulation before rendering?

Comment: Where do I do that? I don't see anything related to baking under particle properties. I have physics turned off because i don't want to render an animation, I just want to render a single frame, if that has anything to do with it maybe.

Comment: In the Particle System panel, under Cache, click on the Bake button

Comment: I don't see a 'cache' option anywhere. I updated the post with a picture of all the tabs present under particle systems.

Comment: That's weird, could you please share your file? (remove all the useless objects) https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It seems to be working now after I removed some objects that I duplicated as backups from the scene. There was probably some overlapping or something going on, since my collections were pretty messy lol. Thanks for your time anyway though haha

Comment: Oh ok great then  ;)  .......